# How do you import an animation for a custom skeleton with model?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

I have a pokemon mesh and I want to rig a skeleton inside of it. I have the animation for the pokemon, but I'm not sure how to go about making a skeleton that looks similar to it so it can work. I've noticed that animations and usually the skeleton look similar to one another, so if I was importing an animation in and I wanted to make a skeleton for that animation, how might I go about this process?

Thank you.

Comment: animation retargeting is the term for what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you i didn't know the correct term for it